# How to calculate the Dynkin index and the Casimir operator for arbitrary representation knowing the fundamental ones

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose I want to find the Dynkin index of the sextet representation $S_2(6)_{SU(3)}$ of $SU(3)$ given that the fundamental is normalized in such a way that $S_2(3)_{SU(3)}=1/2$.

What is the best way to do that?

I guess that I should use the relation

$$
\text{dim}(g)S_2(R)=\text{dim}(R)C_2(R),
$$
where $\text{dim}(g)$ is the group's (i.e., the Lie Algebra's) dimension.

But then, how do I calculate the casimir?

I understand that this is probably a quite formal mathematical development, but I have not found an appropriate reference and appreciate any help.

Comment: You rarely calculate them: in physics, you just look them up, in Slansky, Patera & McKay, etc.... For the method of calculating them, you might try posting in the MSE.

Comment: Table 23 of Slansky, given the Dynkin labels. Further recall there are [*two* different Casimirs for SU(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Casimir_operators). But I don't think this is the SE for Freudenthal's formula.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, I mean the quadratic Casimir. To be honest, I had seen that table from Slansky, but am not sure how to derive the scalar Dynkin number or the Casimir from the Dynkin labels. Eq 3.5 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9207231.pdf) appears to accomplish this. Is this what you mean by WP closed forms? Sorry if this is obvious and thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommended the Math SE because it is a really terrible idea to learn pidgin group theory from papers and questions here. At a minimum, it's best to learn how to use Slansky, Patera & Mc Kay, etc, applications' minded "phonebooks". There are superb group theory books if you wished to get serious, but physicists avoid that like the pandemic.

For SU(3), the closed formulas of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Casimir_operators) suffice. For   *p* quarks and *q* antiquarks, so Dynkin labels [*p,q*], you have the dimension and the quadratic Casimir be
$$
d(p,q)=(p+1)(q+1)(p+q+2)/2, \\ C_2(p,q)= (p^2+q^2+3p+3q+pq)/3.
$$
Hence, for the [2,0], you have *d=* 6, and $C_2=10/3$, so you use the relation you wrote to determine the index
$$
{6\cdot 10/3 \over 8}= 5/2. 
$$
This is the same as the entry for the index in Slansky's Table 23;  which, as you already checked from the fundamental, needs to be halved from his conventions to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your representation has Dynkin labels of $[0, 2]$ because there are zero boxes in the bottom row of the Young tableau and two (more boxes than zero) in the top row. This should be plugged into
\begin{align}
C_2 &= \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sum_{j = 1}^2 (\lambda_j + 2) G^{ji} \lambda_i = 4G^{12} + 8G^{22}
\end{align}
where $G$ is the so called quadratic form matrix. For $SU(N)$ (which has roots all the same length), it is the inverse of the Cartan matrix, which leads to
\begin{equation}
G^{ij} = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The fact that $C_2$ has this relation to the Dynkin labels can be derived in the Cartan-Weyl basis as I mentioned in [a math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492690/quadratic-casimir-of-a-representation-of-son/3534595#3534595) answer, except that was for $SO(N)$.